# I'm using firebase messaging in my flutter app but when I run my project it show Stringtoken=FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase messaging in my flutter app but when I run my project it show String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");

when I run my application it shows this error in the console:

C:\Users\cerbi\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_messaging-9.1.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\messaging\FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java:166: error: cannot find symbol
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");
^
symbol:   variable FirebaseInstanceId
location: class FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

and when I navigate to the specific file stated in the error message here is the code in there

```
        private Task<Map<String, Object>> getToken(Map<String, Object> arguments) {
            return Tasks.call(
                cachedThreadPool,
                () -> {
                  String senderId =
                      arguments.get("senderId") != null
                          ? (String) arguments.get("senderId")
                          : Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
                  String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");
                  return new HashMap<String, Object>() {
                    {
                      put("token", token);
                    }
                  };
                });
          }
```

What can I do to resolve  this problem, it seems that the existing code is not working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token
```

to get token, since

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken
```

is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the current registration token for an app instance, you need to call
`FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();` as stated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client#access_the_registration_token) in their official guide.